# Integer solutions to an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x,y,z$ be positive integers and $S$ be the set of all the solutions to the equation $x^y+y^z=z^x$.  Is $S$ finite or infinite? Lots of thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for information about how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F. Taussing thank u very much for the link to the tutorial.

Comment: what is the source of this problem?

Comment: $(1,1,2)$ is the only solution.

Comment: How is the only solution

Comment: If(1,1,2) is the only solution then we should have a contradiction when at least one of $x$ and  $y$ is greater than 1 but i am unable to see how